# no logoro hacecer que funcione mi login en python con base de datos en mysql

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

espero de todo corazón se encuentren muy bien.
Espero puedan ayudarme ya que estoy aprendiendo a programar de manera autodidacta y estoy intentando hacer un login con t inter y la base de datos de usuarios en mysql, el problema viene cuando intento conectar con la base de datos por que y ni siquiera me imprime la ventana en pantalla, la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal... si me hace falta codigo o puede que este mal acomodado.
Me estoy basando en la documentación oficial.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Espero que me puedan ayudar y no incomodar a nadie, muchas gracias de antemano.

````
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

#tamaño y fondo de la ventana
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title('tejon login')
ventana.geometry('500x500+500+50')
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)
fondo=tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Victor\\Documents\\proyectos python\\cuevita login.png')
fondo1=tk.Label(ventana, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

usuario=tk.StringVar
pasword=tk.StringVar

#entradas
entrada=tk.Entry(ventana, textvar=usuario, width=30, relief='flat', bg='pink')
entrada.place(x=215, y=280)

entrada2=tk.Entry(ventana, textvar=pasword, width=30, relief='flat', bg='pink', show='*')
entrada2.place(x=215, y=350)

#codigo de la base de datos
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='usuario_karina',
                                         user='pynative',
                                         password='pynative@#29')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        ventana.withdraw()
        root2=tk.Tk()
        root2.title('welcome')
        root2.geometry('500x500+500+50')  
        root2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        fondoWelcome=tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Victor\\Documents\\proyectos python\\karina.png')
        fondoWel=tk.Label(root2, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("usuario_karina();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

#ventana de Error
except Error as e:
    ventana.withdraw()
    window=tk.Toplevel()
    window.title('UPS!!!')
    window.geometry('500x500+500+50')  
    window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    fondo=tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Victor\\Documents\\proyectos python\\pupy edit2.gif')
    fondo1=tk.Label(window, image=fondo).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")

ventana.mainloop()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRDuZ.png
````

Comment: a vuelo de pájaro te falta : import mysql.connector para usar las funciones de connector

Comment: si lo habia escrito pero al parecer lo copie mal... disculpa